# Search among two entities

Tags: solr

i am new to solr. I have created two separate entities which are not interrelated.

In db-data-config.xml

```
<entity name="vtab" query="select pid as id, pname as name from ptab order by name asc">
    <field column="panchayat_id" name="panchayat_id" />
    <field column="name" name="name" />
</entity>
<entity name="ptab" query="select vid as id, vname as name from vtab order by name asc">
    <field column="id" name="vid" />
    <field column="name" name="name" />
</entity>
```

In scheme.xml

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>
```

The index is created successfully with this configuration. I want to search by name. If i provide name in query, i want it from any of the table where record is found. With above configuration, i am getting records from only vtab. No records are being searched in ptab. Please guide me where i am going wrong.

Comment: you have named the vtab entity as ptab and vice versa. Can you add <field column="id" name="id" /> to the entity named vtab and check they are indexed properly. Are the ids unique? Ideally, It should search across both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have named the vtab entity as ptab and vice versa.
Can you add  to the entity named vtab and check they are indexed properly.
Are the ids unique? If the ids are duplicate they would override each other.
Ideally, It should search across both

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved. I had declared "id" as primary key, which was being duplicated. I created another field in combination with id-table_name and set it to primary key. Its working properly now. Thank you Mr. Jayendra Patil.

Comment: Cool .. If the solution/answer worked for you. I have added it as an answer. Please accept it as the answer.